# read only required field from standard detail page of community on any profile basis

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, css, lightning-community

in the community, we have a standard detail page where we want to restrict customer to update the status field what we have done until are following.

1. CSS  by a hierarchy of dom inside aura HTML but failed when the client changed the position of the field.
2. we tried on inner HTML

   `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("uiPicklistLabel");
   console.log(elements);
   for(var x=0; x < elements.length; x++)
   {
       console.log(elements[x]);
       if(elements[x].children[0].innerHTML="Status"){
           console.log(elements[x].children[0].innerHTML);
          elements[x].nextSibling.classList.add("statusactivecss");
       }
   }`

and add CSS to added class.

it's working fine while direct use in the console but in `ltng:require scripts=` DOM change later when we click edit and again fail to hide any suggestion related to this

[image: Refer]

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can you not make that "Status" field read only for the community profiles?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I want to restrict some field for any  profile to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make read-only the status field to Community Users and any other profile as well as you cannot remove it from a Page layout. One Way is that you can write a validation rule based on the Community User profile and restrict that user from changing the value.

The validation rule can be something like that.

```
ISCHANGED(Status) && $Profile.Name = 'Community Profile Name'
```

If you want to allow certain statuses while creating a new case you can add that exception as well like, let's say you want to allow the new case can only have 'New' status when it is created by a community user, you can tweak the validation rule like below.

```
$Profile.Name = 'Community Profile Name' && ((ISNEW() && !ISPICKVAL(Status, 'New')) || (!ISNEW() && ISCHANGED(Status) ))
```